# Problem Using Class function as callback

Tags: ros, c++, ros-fuerte, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to encapsulate nodes to support dynamic node creation.  When I try to register a callback from inside a class using one of that classes functions I get a compile error. The following code works correctly if I do `static callback()`.

```
class node {
    private:
        ros::NodeHandle *n;
    public:
        node(int argc, char **argv, std::string s) {
            n = NULL;
            ros::init(argc, argv, s);
        }

        bool node::create() {
        if (n == NULL) {
        n = new ros::NodeHandle();
        return true;
        }

        return false;
        }

    ros::NodeHandle getHandle() {return *n;}
};

class coordinator
{
    private:
        node myNode;
        ros::Subscriber sub;

    public:
        void setup() {
            //assume myNode() has been called correctly
            myNode.create();
            //this does not compile
            sub = myNode.getHandle().subscribe("telemetry", 1000, &coordinator::callback);
        }
        void callback(const TelemetryUpdate::ConstPtr& msg) {;/** stuff */}
};
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64446/problem-using-class-function-as-callback/) by [kaoao](https://answers.ros.org/users/5069/kaoao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you review the [ROS Cpp Publisher and Subscriber Overview](http://ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers), you will find that you need to also pass a reference to the instance of the object.

In this case, you would probably want to do:

```
sub = myNode.getHandle().subscribe("telemetry", 1000, &coordinator::callback, this);
```

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kaoao](https://answers.ros.org/users/5069/kaoao/) on 2013-06-06**:
Thanks, I forgot about the `this` keyword.